# Having Troubles with Unity C# Time Delay / Coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write a script for when you press a button to make it instantiate a card with a random rarity but I need to delete the cards after a small delay although I dont think the delay is working because the cards seemingly instantly dissapear

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CardMasterScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] CardArray = new GameObject[8];
    public float RollNumber;

    public void RollCard()
    {
        RollNumber = Random.Range(0.1f, 100);

        Debug.Log("Number Rolled: " + RollNumber);

        if(RollNumber <= 47.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[0]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
            Destroy(card);
        } else if(RollNumber > 47.9 && RollNumber <= 77.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[1]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
            Destroy(card);
        } else if( RollNumber > 77.9 && RollNumber <= 87.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[2]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
            Destroy(card);
        } else if(RollNumber > 87.9 && RollNumber <= 94.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[3]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
            Destroy(card);
        } else if(RollNumber > 94.9 && RollNumber <= 97.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[4]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
            Destroy(card);
        } else if(RollNumber > 97.9 && RollNumber <= 99.4)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[5]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
            Destroy(card);
        } else if(RollNumber > 99.4 && RollNumber <= 99.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[6]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
            Destroy(card);
        } else if (RollNumber > 99.9 && RollNumber <= 100)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[7]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
            Destroy(card);
        }
    }
    
    public IEnumerator TimeDelay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }
}
```

- please help me fix this issue if you know how and thank you in advance!

at first I thought it was a problem with the instantiating and that it just wasn't instantiating the cards at all but now I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Comment: Sidenote: `RollNumber = Random.Range(0.1f, 100);` looks a bit odd ^^ if all you want to do is ensure it uses the `float` instead of the `int` version why not just use `RollNumber = Random.Range(0f, 100f);` ;)

Comment: Also note that all the `RollNumber > 47.9 &&` are redundant since this is `else if` and previous values would already have been covered by the previous `if(RollNumber <= 47.9)` ..  also you probably want to use `float` there as well .. no need to use `double` => `47.9` etc should rather be `47.9f` etc

Answer (score 1):

you have to call the destroy after the waiting time  like this

```
public IEnumerator TimeDelay(){    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    Destroy(obj);
}
```

and other tip: Destroy method contains delay parameter

```
Destroy(obj,0.5f);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html

Answer (score 0):

The destruction is occurring independent from the coroutine. When you start the coroutine, you are "splitting" the program into two branches. Currently your first branch just turns on an alarm clock for half a second and your other branch deletes your object.

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CardMasterScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] CardArray = new GameObject[8];
    public float RollNumber;

    public void RollCard()
    {
        RollNumber = Random.Range(0.1f, 100);

        Debug.Log("Number Rolled: " + RollNumber);

        if(RollNumber <= 47.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[0]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
        } else if(RollNumber > 47.9 && RollNumber <= 77.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[1]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
        } else if( RollNumber > 77.9 && RollNumber <= 87.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[2]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
        } else if(RollNumber > 87.9 && RollNumber <= 94.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[3]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
        } else if(RollNumber > 94.9 && RollNumber <= 97.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[4]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
        } else if(RollNumber > 97.9 && RollNumber <= 99.4)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[5]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
        } else if(RollNumber > 99.4 && RollNumber <= 99.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[6]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
        } else if (RollNumber > 99.9 && RollNumber <= 100)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[7]);
            StartCoroutine(TimeDelay());
        }
    }
    
    public IEnumerator TimeDelay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        Destroy(card);
    }
}
```

In your case using a coroutine isn't actually necessery, since the [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) method has a build in delay argument.

Streamlined your code could look like this:

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CardMasterScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] CardArray = new GameObject[8];
    public float RollNumber;

    public void RollCard()
    {
        RollNumber = Random.Range(0.1f, 100);

        Debug.Log("Number Rolled: " + RollNumber);
        GameObject card = null;
        if(RollNumber <= 47.9)
        {
            card = Instantiate(CardArray[0]);
        } else if(RollNumber <= 77.9)
        {
            card = Instantiate(CardArray[1]);
        } else if(RollNumber <= 87.9)
        {
            card = Instantiate(CardArray[2]);
        } else if(RollNumber <= 94.9)
        {
            card = Instantiate(CardArray[3]);
        } else if(RollNumber <= 97.9)
        {
            card = Instantiate(CardArray[4]);
        } else if(RollNumber <= 99.4)
        {
            card = Instantiate(CardArray[5]);
        } else if(RollNumber <= 99.9)
        {
            card = Instantiate(CardArray[6]);
        } else
        {
            card = Instantiate(CardArray[7]);
        }
        Destroy(card, 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just reposting here as well: note that all the `RollNumber > 47.9 &&` are redundant since this is `else if` and previous values would already have been covered by the previous `if(RollNumber <= 47.9)` ..  also you probably want to use `float` there as well .. no need to use `double` => `47.9` etc should rather be `47.9f` etc

Comment: And `Destroy(card, 0.5f);` can't be used if you introduced a couple of closed scopes with `var card` ;) you want a `GameObject card = null;` before the first `if` and then within assign that `card = ...` .. indeed you could rather only set the index and have a single `Destroy(Instantiate(CardArray[index]), 0.5f);`

Comment: @derHugo Oh, yeah! You are completely right, The point about the card variable is indeed a bug, but the other points are also cool, I will mod my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Quick way, it is enough to enter the delay value in the second parameter of the `Destroy` method.

```cs
Destroy(card, .5f); // Delay Time
```

The second way is to write the functions themselves inside the `Coroutine`. Because the delay time is not executed outside the coroutine.

```cs
private IEnumerator DelayRun(GameObject gameObject)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
    
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

The third way is to specify the action with a delay time, which allows you to execute any command after a delay. Just make sure you use the `System` library.

```cs
using System;

...

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(DelayRun(.5f, () => Destroy(card)));
}

private IEnumerator DelayRun(float delay, Action action)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    
    action.Invoke();
}
```