# How to create an array for UI elements with children in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a system for when you press a button it instantiates a random card for a card game, but I can't figure out how to create an array for the cards (the cards are just ui images with some text on them (the image being a parent)) although using the refrence "Gameobject" although since the cards are ui elements not acctual game objects it didn't work so i tried using the refrence "Image" but then it only instantiated the actual image part. - pls help i know its a bit confusing but if u can help pls do i have only been programming for just over a year now so i am not very good with problems like this /:

code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CardMasterScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image[] CardArray = new Image[8];
    public float RollNumber;
    public Canvas ParentCanvas;

    public void RollCard()
    {
        RollNumber = Random.Range(0.1f, 100);

        Debug.Log("Number Rolled: " + RollNumber);

        if(RollNumber <= 47.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[0]);
            card.transform.SetParent(ParentCanvas.transform);
            Destroy(card, 0.5f);
        } else if(RollNumber > 47.9 && RollNumber <= 77.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[1]);
            card.transform.SetParent(ParentCanvas.transform);
            Destroy(card, 0.5f);
        } else if( RollNumber > 77.9 && RollNumber <= 87.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[2]);
            card.transform.SetParent(ParentCanvas.transform);
            Destroy(card, 0.5f);
        } else if(RollNumber > 87.9 && RollNumber <= 94.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[3]);
            card.transform.SetParent(ParentCanvas.transform);
            Destroy(card, 0.5f);
        } else if(RollNumber > 94.9 && RollNumber <= 97.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[4]);
            card.transform.SetParent(ParentCanvas.transform);
            Destroy(card, 0.5f);
        } else if(RollNumber > 97.9 && RollNumber <= 99.4)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[5]);
            card.transform.SetParent(ParentCanvas.transform);
            Destroy(card, 0.5f);
        } else if(RollNumber > 99.4 && RollNumber <= 99.9)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[6]);
            card.transform.SetParent(ParentCanvas.transform);
            Destroy(card, 0.5f);
        } else if (RollNumber > 99.9 && RollNumber <= 100)
        {
            var card = Instantiate(CardArray[7]);
            card.transform.SetParent(ParentCanvas.transform);
            Destroy(card, 0.5f);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

i have tried changing the refrence in the array to image, i expected unity to just instantiate the image and its children aswell but it only instantiated the image.

Comment: What was the problem with [what you had before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75351274/having-troubles-with-unity-c-sharp-time-delay-coroutines) ...? Also you seem to be immune against any suggestions anyway so why ask another question without even reacting to any of the comments and answers in your previous question ...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't create 8 GameObjects that have an image attached to them and have your `CardArray` be a GameObject array instead. Also the `Instantiate` function may have a transform argument to set its parent to.

For instance you can replace

```
var card = Instantiate(CardArray[0]);
 card.transform.SetParent(ParentCanvas.transform);
```

by

```
var card = Instantiate(CardArray[0], ParentCanvas.transform);
```

An Image alone doesn't have any children, it needs to be attached to an object that has some. That is why you can't instantiate an Image and expect it to have children

Hope that helps,